# .htaccess - add www and direct all to root level

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like all requests to be directed to the root page. I also need `www` to be added if it has been missed out. I have tried numerous attempts but can not seem to get it to work, latest attempt

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule !^.*/ / [NC,L]
```

This code below works providing that they do not use `www` within their requests.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this single rule as your first rule  in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file::

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this rule tales long to load and then finally loads the page but broken?

Comment: So you're getting 404 or some other error? Have you tried in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: I'm not getting a 404, i'm getting the page but with broken images and no styling etc. I've tried it in multiple browsers, emptied chache and on my mobile device.

Comment: Perfect thanks alot! I wish i understood what was going on within the code  :)

Comment: Actually this rule is not that difficult. It means if www is not in host (condition1) OR If URI is not `/` (condition2) AND request is not for a file then redirect to `http://www.domain.com/`

Comment: I need to do something else similar to this on another site i'm modifying. I need to add WWW and redirect all traffic to another site apart from one directory. Shall I open another question for it?

Comment: Yes please open a new question and I will try my best to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i've opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056224/htaccess-redirect-all-traffic-to-another-site-apart-from-requests-within-a-di