# .htaccess - Redirect all traffic to another site apart from requests within a directory, also add WWW

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to add `www` to the url and then direct all traffic to another domain if the request/s are not within a directory. I tired the following code but it redirects everything, including the `directory1` folder name

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^directory1/$ /directory1/ [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory1/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very close but the only issue is that it redirects `directory1` if you don't put `www`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to work well. You're very good at .htaccess